# Draw two contours in image by matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, contour

I am using contour function in matlab to draw the boundary of a image I that ranges from -2 to 2. It is done by bellow code. I want to draw a new contour overlaps in the current contour in orignal image.

That color contour is yellow color. The yellow contour is created based on the position in mask. Note that mask is extacted from orignal image, but only choose some position as the bellow figure. My expected result is such as output image. Could you help me to solve my problem?

This is my code to draw the contour in Orignal Image

```
 %% Draw contour in Orignal 
 %%Create image I
I= ones(10)*2;
I(3:8,3:8) = -1;
I(5:6,5:6) = -2;
I(3:8,3)=1;
I(3:8,8)=1;
I(8,3:8)=1;
I(3,3:8)=1;
%% Mask
mask=zeros(10);
mask(3,5:6) = 1;
mask(5:6,3) = 1;
mask(4,5:6) = -1;
mask(5:6,4) = -1;
imagesc(uint8(I),[-2 2]),colormap(gray),axis off;axis equal,
hold on
[c,h] = contour(I,[0 0],'r','Linewidth',3);
```

[image]
UPDATE ISSUE: Based on the sugeestion of Daniel, his code work well for above input. However, I check with new input, it does not work. Let see the new input

```
    I=[   2     2     2     2     2     2     2     2     2
         2     2     2     1     1     2     2     2     2
         2     1     1    -1    -1     1     2     2     2
         2    -1    -1     0    -1     1     2     2     2
         1    -1     0    -1     1     2     2     2     2
         1    -1    -1     1     2     2     2     2     2
         1    -1     1     2     2     2     2     2     2
         1     1     2     2     2     2     2     2     2
         2     2     2     2     2     2     2     2     2];
 mask=[  NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
         NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
         NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
         NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN    -1     1   NaN   NaN   NaN
         NaN   NaN   NaN    -1     1   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
         NaN   NaN    -1     1   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
         NaN    -1     1   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
         NaN     1   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
         NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN];

%%Daniel code
imagesc(uint8(I),[-2 2]),colormap(gray),axis off;axis equal,
hold on
[c,h] = contour(I,[0 0],'r','Linewidth',3);
[c,h] = contour(mask,[0 0],'g','Linewidth',3);
```

This is output. What is happen with above code. Could you fix it help me?
[image]

Comment: It would also be good if you added the code that generates that data. Make it easy for people...

Answer (score 1):

You initialised your mask with zero, that created some more contours than you intended to have. Initalize with nan

```
 %% Draw contour in Orignal 
 %%Create image I
I= ones(10)*2;
I(3:8,3:8) = -1;
I(5:6,5:6) = -2;
I(3:8,3)=1;
I(3:8,8)=1;
I(8,3:8)=1;
I(3,3:8)=1;
%% Mask
mask=nan(10);
mask(3,5:6) = 1;
mask(5:6,3) = 1;
mask(4,5:6) = -1;
mask(5:6,4) = -1;
imagesc(uint8(I),[-2 2]),colormap(gray),axis off;axis equal,
hold on
[c,h] = contour(I,[0 0],'r','Linewidth',3);
[c,h] = contour(mask,[0 0],'g','Linewidth',3);
```

Regarding your Update:

Your mask does not define a contour, it lacks to many surrounding elements. Try a larger mask:

```
mask=nan(size(I));
mask(4:8,2:6)=I(4:8,2:6);
```

Comment: Thank Daniel so much, However, mask is a input from other function that proceduce such my code. Based on your code, I must convert my mask to NaN. How to conver it to same your mask from my mask

Comment: Use `mask(mask==0)=nan` to convert.

Comment: Let see my update question (new input), your code did not work well. Could you chek help me?